# Does WebStorm have an issue with caching data?

Tags: javascript, express, webstorm

When I run code in WebStorm, sometimes despite making changes to the code, the changes don't reflect in the browser.  If I take that same code and put it into VS Code it will work properly and suddenly my WebStorm application will start to work.

The most recent example is when I run the following code in WebStorm and use `nodemon server.js` :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/messages', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello')
});

const server = app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log(`server is listening on port ${server.address().port}`)
});
```

In WebStorm, if I terminate nodemon and change the port to `4000` and re-run `nodemon server.js`, WebStorm's terminal states `server is listening on port 4000`

Furthermore, when navigating to 'http://localhost:4000/messages' `Cannot GET /messages` appears instead of `hello`.

When I instead run this code in VS Code, everything works as intended.  I've had similar issues with buggy CSS when trying to use JetBrains IDE Support plugin to live update.

Comment: WebStorm definitely doesn't cache anything. Must be a problem with a way you start your app

Comment: Hmm any idea on what it could be?